# Regular expression matching my condition

Tags: regex

I have added this regular expression in my code

```
\s\$\w+\.*\w+%*\s
```

I thought it would match and tokenize the below scenario in my input string:

1. $var1 $var2
2. $var1

   $var2

I observe that case 2 it splits my input as 2 matches, var1, var2. But in case 1 $var1 is considered a match and $var2 is ignored . Would case it not fall into my RE as-"any word that starts with space followed with dollar ends with space" and split my input as 2 matches? If not could anybody please explain the way to correct it as well as tell me why the above RE fails.

Here is the code:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    str = " " + str;
    String pattern = (StringConstants.PATTERN_DOLLER_VALUE);
    Pattern patternComplie = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(configTemplateString)) {
        Matcher matcherConfigTemplateString = patternComplie
                .matcher(configTemplateString);
        while (matcherConfigTemplateString.find()) {
            String placeHolder = matcherConfigTemplateString.group();
            System.out.println("placeholder :" + placeHolder);
            values.add(matcherConfigTemplateString.group().trim());
```

The "PATTERN_DOLLER_VALUE" has the pattern that I mentioned above. Values is a arraylist which hols tokens.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes- How do I do that?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes If you read the question you will find that in fact the second one is the one that works for OP.

Comment: If you just want to match all the $vars, you can simply use \$\w+/g

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected. The question is worded quite cryptic with numbered cases and vars  :P

Comment: @Sergio I tired that as well, It does not work. Tried this as well-(\s\$\w+\s)*

Comment: On Java this should work, but there's no need to make it global. Like this: http://ideone.com/PqvHdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with missing whitespace at the end of your Case 1. You add a space manually before the string, but you are not adding it after.

What I suggest is check if there are no word characters before and after the token with look-arounds, and `str = " " + str;` will become redundant.

To match all the `$xx.x%`-like tokens, you can use [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/rU0dR4/3):

```
(?<!\\w)\\$\\w+\\.*\\w+%*(?!\\w)
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/QM4gQj)

Or, try adding a space at the end of the string, too (`str = " " + str + " ";`).

Comment: @stribizhev- Thanks so much! it works.I remember trying with adding a space in the end. Strange that it did not work. The only problem was me checking for spaces in the end. Thanks again